# Find specfic HTML tag with poorly formed closing tag

Tags: regex

I'm having problems refining a REGEX find/replace for a specific XHTML tag (in this example, IMG tags) that don't have */>* closing tags.

Consider this two-lines example text:

```
<div id="newdocs-logo"><img src="../../../_DOC_DEPT/common/logo-white-250w.gif" alt="CloudPassage logo" height="38" width="251" /></div> 

<p class="newdocs-indent"><img src="CSM/config-scanning.png" width="692" height="359"></p>
```

The following REGEX works properly only if I include `a-z` in capture group #3's negated character class:

```
(<img)(.*?)([^a-z\/])(\>)
```

Replacement string:

```
$1$2$3/$4
```

I have to include `a-z` in the character class BECAUSE if I don't, then in line 1 of the example text the REGEX continues past the properly closed IMG tag and finds the closing tag of the DIV tag. I've gone 'round in circles experimenting with look-aheads/behinds and so on but can't come up with anything better.

[image: Illustration of working and non-working REGEX]

SO although I have a workable solution, I'm keen to learn if there's a more elegant way to do this that doesn't require `a-z` in the negated character class.

Comment: Have you considered using a proper HTML parser? They tend to handle non-XHTML-conforming things like `<img>` just fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of the thread that concludes with "[You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1477364)".

Comment: doesn't look like `(<img)(.*?)([^[a-z\/])(\>)` would work at all since `[^[a-z\/]` has an unmatched `[`

Comment: I fully expected the old "you can't parse HTML with REGEX" thing. But I don't really believe I'm *parsing* HTML, merely looking for a particular text pattern. This seems consistent with the multitude of REGEX print and online resources that invariably include examples of using REGEX to find -- and replace -- specific HTML patterns...

Comment: Also, fixed the extra "[" that somehow got into my example. (The REGEX I'm using doesn't have it. And works as described...

Comment: How are you using the regex?  I tried it on https://regex101.com/ and it didn't capture both img tags.  Can you post the output that you are seeing/expect?

Comment: Concerns about parsing HTML with regex aside, I can't figure out why this wouldn't work: `s/(<img .*?)(?!\/>)>/$1\/>/`. Clearly I've got some learning to do!

Comment: @miken32, `(<img .*?)(?!\/>)>/$1\/>` does match both image tags for php-style regex!  Make sure you're doing a global search though so both results are returned - `s/` probably means single line in whatever language you're using.

Comment: @mgamba he's not looking to match both, only the one that's not closed properly

Comment: Note that I added a screenshot that illustrated the proximate issue. With *a-z* in character class, REGEX works (in both the example and in the HTML I was fixing). Without *a-z* in character class, search continues to end of DIV tag in first example string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually really simple to do with a regex. Empty tags like `img` are actually really regular.

Assuming that there is at least one one character between `img` and `>`, this regex will work:

```
(<img[^>]*[^\/])>
```

Basically, it captures `<img`, then everything until the last character before the `>`. If that character is not `/`, you will get the match, and can use the replacement string: `$1/>`.

(If you don't get a match, then your tag is already closed properly.)

Comment: Yes, since I originally posted this I've learned the "trick" of negated character classes. As in, intentionally not finding something is sometimes a form of REGEX success...

Comment: @RBV Yes, I knew this was an old question when I answered it. But all the new questions are FGITW. Hopefully it might help someone else in the future...